# SNX network extender with multi factor auth checkpoint VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Hi I have the snx network extender by checkpoint vpn and I want to connect to my office ntwork.
Once I type `snx -s "my vpn" -u "user"` it asks my password.
My office VPN is set to insert an additional OTP recevide on my mobil phone, but once I confirm the password on the terminal the client gives me "access failed" and at the same time I recive the OTP.
Do you know if there is any additional option to configure when launching the command snx?
Thanks.
`